# Why are Doubleclick cookies appearing on one browser and not another, for the same site?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, cookies

I have a question about advertising cookies, as someone who doesn't understand them all that well, but would like to understand better how tracking works.

I'm looking at [this website](http://national-lottery.co.uk). In Chrome on my local machine, with all browser extensions disabled, if I clear site cookies via `chrome://settings/siteData`, then load the site and click 'Accept Cookies', I see multiple third-party cookies in DevTools, e.g. from `doubleclick.net`:

[image]

Loading the site in Safari on the same machine, the `doubleclick.net` domain appears under the list of cookie origins, but no cookies appear:

[image]

And finally, loading the site on Chrome on another machine (also with cookies cleared, and no browser extensions enabled), DevTools doesn't show any third-party cookies, only first-party cookies.

Two questions:

1. Is this site genuinely setting third-party ad cookies, given how differently the cookies appear in different browsers? Or could these cookies actually be set by some ad tracker running on my local browser/machine, even though I've disabled all browser extensions? Basically, what is going on?
2. In Safari, what might be happening to make the `doubleclick.net` domain appear in the list of origins, when it appears there are no actual cookies being set?

If relevant: I'm logged in to Google on the first browser, but not the second two. And I have 'Do Not Track' switched on on the first browser.

Comment: Strange if  'Do Not Track' has the opposite effect. Try setting it on the second Chrome. Try also disabling it on the first Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for the difference in the trackers. But the top reason is that Safari **blocks** them. Chrome is a browser I wouldn't prefer if I want privacy , because chrome is owned by Google and Google earns by selling trackers. Obviously chrome wouldn't **block** them. You can get a report of all the blocked trackers on safari by clicking the 'Privacy Report' on the home page of safari.

Safari blocked all these trackers on that site of yours-
[image: privacy report]

A more detailed explanation can be found here - https://support.apple.com/en-hk/guide/safari/sfri11471/mac.

Comment: this answer could be improved by providing a source from which it is evident that safari effectively blocks cookies (such as a safari help page or similar).